# Multiple determination in terms of simple determination

Tags: self-study, r-squared

I'm working through *Applied Linear Regression Models* (Kutner) and having a hard time figuring out  this problem (it's actually problem 6.26):

> Given a First-Order Model with Two Predictors:  $Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_1 + \beta_2X_2 + \epsilon$ , show that the coefficient of simple determination between $Y$ and $\hat{Y}$ equals the coefficient of multiple determination of $R^2$.

I've also seen this problem in other texts as well - it seems to be a common problem, yet I have not been able to find any kind of proof online.  Does anyone have a link to or can someone show me how to show they are equal?

Comment: This can be viewed either as a routine exercise in plugging in formulas or as a way to stretch your understanding of regression.  In the first instance, remember that the hat matrix is a projection (whence equal to its square). In the second case, interpret $R^2$ and $r^2$ in terms of the variance of the residuals, recognizing that the residuals of $\mathbf{Y}$ vs. $\mathbf{X}$ must be the same as the residuals of $\mathbf{Y}$  vs. $\hat{\mathbf{Y}}$.